# How to get documentation in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have my .Net project. Now, I want to create my project document for this project. Is there any tool in Visual Studio 2013 that can help me to build a document based on the comments added for different classes, functions, etc.?

Comment: Ghost doc will help you to write comments, and sand castle should help you to build documentation file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# documentation generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-sharp-documentation-generator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) will help you

GhostDoc is a Visual Studio extension that automatically generates XML documentation comments for methods and properties based on their type, parameters, name, and other contextual information.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641369/426028)

---

Right-click on your project node in Solution Explorer and choose Properties (or press Alt-Enter).

In Properties view choose `Build` on the left side menu.

In the Output section select the XML documentation file checkbox (and optionally change the path or file name).

Documentation comments are automatically built into the specified xml file.

[image: project properties]

See also [Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If, as suggested above, you enable 'XML documentation file' output from your project build settings, VS will generate documentation XMLs detailing the members of each class in your project.  You can then use the MS SandCastle tool to convert these XMLs to MSDN-style help docs and/or HTMLs.   On top of the auto-generated documentation you can also add ///XML comments to your classes and public members to provide further information.  However, I'd suggest not getting too carried away with in-code documentation other than a high-level overview of the class. Otherwise you run the risk of your comments getting out of sync with your code, especially after refactoring. The only thing less helpful than no comments are incorrect comments for your code.